# Transfer data from Javascript to Pyscript

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, pyscript

Im trying to build a website where you have a canvas, 28x28 sized and you draw a number. This is all handled through classic HTML, css and Javascript. Hovewever, once the image is drawn, I want to store that as an array (pixel drawn is a 0, and pixel not drawn is valued 255), and pass it onto a python algorithm that I have, that uses the k-nearest neighbors algorithm to try and determine which number it is.

All the code is already done, the only issue im having is trying to get that javascript array into my pyscript.

Im not proffiecient in javascript, so im having trouble writing my own code with it, but I think all the code is written, except that communication between js and Pyscript

CODE IN HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My OCR project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css"/>
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Optical Character Recognition</h1>
        <p align = "center">Este proyecto está hecho por Luca Siegel usando una mezcla de Python, Pyscript, HTML, JavaScript y CSS. 
            El objetivo es dibujar un numero de 28x28 pixeles en el canvas y que un algoritmo de machine learning llamado knn 
            (k-nearest-neighbors) sea capaz de distinguirlo comparándolo con la database de MNIST. Actualmente hay una probabilidad de acierto
            de alrededor del 80%.

        </p>

        <canvas id="gridCanvas" width="420px" height="420px"></canvas>
        <button id="clearButton">Limpiar</button>
        <button id="processButton">Procesar</button>
        <py-script >
            import time

            DATA_DIR = r"C:/Users/lucas/Downloads/OCR/"
            TEST_DIR = r"C:/Users/lucas/Downloads/OCR/test/"
            TEST_DATA_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"
            TEST_LABELS_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte"
            TRAIN_DATA_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "train-images.idx3-ubyte"
            TRAIN_LABELS_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "train-labels.idx1-ubyte"
            start_time = time.time()
            DEBUG = True
            if DEBUG:
                from PIL import Image
                import numpy as np
                
                def read_image(path):
                    return np.asarray(Image.open(path).convert("L"))
                def write_image(image,path):
                    img = Image.fromarray(np.array(image),"L")
                    img.save(path)
            def bytes_to_int(byte_data):
                return int.from_bytes(byte_data,"big")


            def read_labels(filename,n_max_labels = None):
                labels = [] #variable que guarda todas las imagenes
                with open(filename, "rb") as f: #abrir el fichero filename como f, y leerlo en binario ("rb")
                    _  =f.read(4) #numero inutil (representa algo que no necesitamos)
                    #los siguientes 12 bytes representan el numero de imagenes, el numero de filas y de columnas
                    n_labels = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
                    if n_max_labels:
                        n_labels = n_max_labels
                    for label_idx in range(n_labels):
                        label = f.read(1)
                        labels.append(label)
                        
                return labels

            count = 0

            def read_images(filename,n_max_images = None):
                global count
                images = [] #variable que guarda todas las imagenes
                with open(filename, "rb") as f: #abrir el fichero filename como f, y leerlo en binario ("rb")
                    _  =f.read(4) #numero inutil (representa algo que no necesitamos)
                    #los siguientes 12 bytes representan el numero de imagenes, el numero de filas y de columnas
                    n_images = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
                    if n_max_images:
                        n_images = n_max_images
                    n_rows = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
                    n_columns = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
                    for image_idx in range(n_images):
                        image = []#variable que guarda la imagen actual
                        for row_idx in range(n_rows):
                            row = []#variable que guarda la columna actual
                            for column_idx in range(n_columns):
                                count += 1
                                pixel = f.read(1) #leemos el pixel actual de 8 bits y lo apendizamos a la row
                                row.append(pixel)
                            image.append(row)#metemos la row en la image
                        images.append(image)#metemos la image en el conjunto de images
                return images

            def aplanar_lista(l):
                return [pixel for sublist in l for pixel in sublist]


            def pasar_lista_unidimensional(X):
                return [aplanar_lista(sample) for sample in X]

            def dist(x,y):
                return sum((bytes_to_int(x_i) - bytes_to_int(y_i)) **2 for x_i,y_i in zip(x,y))**0.5 #distancia euclides
                
                
            def distancia_entre_samples(X_train,test_sample):
                return [dist(train_sample,test_sample) for train_sample in X_train] #por todas las imagenes, calculamos su distancia arriba

            def most_frequent_element(list):
                return max(list, key= list.count)


            def knn(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test, k = 3):
                y_pred = [] #la prediccion que tenemos a los x_test
                for test_sample_idx,test_sample in enumerate(X_test):
                    training_distances = distancia_entre_samples(X_train,test_sample) #queremos conseguir las distancias a todos los puntos
                    sorted_distance_indices = [
                        pair[0]
                        for pair in sorted(enumerate(training_distances), key = lambda x: x[1]) ]#escogemos la menor distancia
                    candidates = [bytes_to_int(y_train[idx]) for idx in sorted_distance_indices[:k]] # k mejores candidatos
                    top_candidate = most_frequent_element(candidates)
                    y_pred.append(top_candidate) #apuntamos a predicción
                return y_pred
            def main():
                
                #"X" es igual al dataset y "y" es el label asignado
                X_train = read_images(TRAIN_DATA_FILENAME,1000)
                X_test = read_images(TEST_DATA_FILENAME,500)
                y_train = read_labels(TRAIN_LABELS_FILENAME,1000)
                y_test = read_labels(TEST_LABELS_FILENAME,500)
                if DEBUG:
                    for idx,test_sample in enumerate(X_test):
                        write_image(test_sample,f"{TEST_DIR}{idx}.png")
                #inputear nuestra propia imagen
                    X_test= [read_image(f"{TEST_DIR}mitest.png")]
                    print(X_test)
                
                
                X_train = pasar_lista_unidimensional(X_train) #queremos pasar la matriz de valores a una matriz unidimensional
                X_test = pasar_lista_unidimensional(X_test)
                print(X_test)
                
                y_pred = knn(X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test,5)
                accuracy = sum([bytes_to_int(y_pred_i) == y_test_i 
                                for y_pred_i,y_test_i 
                                in zip(y_test,y_pred)
                                ])/len(y_test)
                end_time = time.time()
                print("The number you have just written is: " ,y_pred, "Time that it took to guess:", round(end_time-start_time,5), " Seconds")
                print("Number of iterations: ", count)
                
                
                
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()
        </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CODE IN JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('gridCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const gridSize = 28;
    const cellSize = canvas.width / gridSize;
    let isDrawing = false;

    // Función para dibujar la cuadrícula
    function drawGrid() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (let i = 1; i < gridSize; i++) {
            const pos = i * cellSize;
            // Líneas verticales
            ctx.moveTo(pos, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(pos, canvas.height);
            // Líneas horizontales
            ctx.moveTo(0, pos);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, pos);
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function clearGrid() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawGrid();
    }

    function getGridValues() {
        const gridValues = [];

        for (let y = 0; y < gridSize; y++) {
            const row = [];
            for (let x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
                const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, 1, 1).data;
                const isLightColor = imageData[0] + imageData[1] + imageData[2] > 255 * 3 / 2; // Más de la mitad del valor máximo (blanco)
                row.push(dec2bin(isLightColor ? 255 : 0));
            }
            gridValues.push(row);
        }
        return gridValues;
    }

    function downloadImage() {
        const imageDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = imageDataURL;

        image.onload = function() {
            const resizedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const resizedCtx = resizedCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Establece el nuevo tamaño
            resizedCanvas.width = gridSize;
            resizedCanvas.height = gridSize;

            // Copia la parte del dibujo sin los bordes de la cuadrícula
            resizedCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, gridSize * cellSize, gridSize * cellSize, 0, 0, gridSize, gridSize);

            // Descarga la imagen redimensionada
            const resizedDataURL = resizedCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = resizedDataURL;
            a.download = 'grid.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        };
        sendGridValues(getGridValues());
    }
    function dec2bin(dec) {
        return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
      }


    // Función para manejar el evento de dibujo
    function handleDraw(event) {
        if (!isDrawing) return;

        const x = Math.floor(event.offsetX / cellSize);
        const y = Math.floor(event.offsetY / cellSize);

        // Dibuja en la celda correspondiente
        ctx.fillRect(x * cellSize, y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }

    // Dibuja la cuadrícula inicial
    drawGrid();

    // Agrega eventos para dibujar en el lienzo
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
        isDrawing = true;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleDraw);

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
        isDrawing = false;
         // Muestra los valores de la cuadrícula después de terminar de dibujar
    });

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isDrawing = false;
    });

    document.getElementById('clearButton').addEventListener('click', clearGrid);
    document.getElementById('processButton').addEventListener('click', downloadImage);
});
```

Comment: your code is completely irrelevant to the question. Your question is just **How do you submit data to an endpoint with JS?** I highly recommend you to read into `JSON` and either the `submit` method or `fetch`+ `POST` method. submitting to an endpoint is independent of the backend language.

Comment: I think this comment is incorrect - this is not about submitting data to an endpoint, but rather how the Python/JS FFI works in PyScript/Pyodide.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

It looks like you're still using the `alpha` release of PyScript from 2022, which has had many releases since then. I recommending updating your js/css links to:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.2.1/core.css"/>
<script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.2.1/core.js"></script>
```

Second, you need to instruct PyScript to load the packages you want to use - in this cases, Pillow and Numpy. You can do this using the [packages keys](https://pyscript.github.io/docs/2024.2.1/user-guide/configuration/#packages) in py-config, like so:

```
<py-config>
    packages = ['pillow', 'numpy']
</py-config>
```

With those corrections, we run into the local files issue you [asked about in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046199/using-files-in-pyscript) - without those files, there's not much further we can take the troubleshooting here.